# Curve the transition to an inset face

Tags: geometry, bevel

I'm attempting to replicate this geometry:

[image: Geometry to replicate]

The main difficulty is curving that middle section. I have this currently, but am stumped on trying to graduate between the 2 selected edge loops:

[image: Current geometry]

Instead of the hard step from the inset, is there a way to curve between those 2 edges? The bevel tool doesn't quite do what I want it to and all the resources I google for "bevelling" are about round the corners of the shape, rather than between 2 edges.

EDIT:
Bevelling the centre edge doesn't curve, just adds loop cuts:
[image]

Comment: the bevel should work fine, what's the problem?

Comment: sorry should have explained, see edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I had the `Profile` variable set to `1`! So it was trying to square everything off!

Changed the bevel settings to this to resolve my issue - [image]

Comment: Hey :). You can also use custom bevel profile to create the whole shape in one go.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! If you solved your problem, make sure to mark your answer as the solution by clicking the checkmark next to it. This helps others find a solution to your problem.

Comment: I will do, just 20 hours to go before I can accept my own answer :)